# Change background image on panorama on WP7 when user scrolls across

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, panorama-control

Just wondering if anyone knows of a way to change the panorama background image dynamically when the user scrolls across on windows phone 7?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the Xaml do:

```
     <controls:Panorama Title="my application" SelectionChanged="Panorama_SelectionChanged">
        <controls:Panorama.Background>
            <ImageBrush x:Name="myImg" ImageSource="PanoramaBackground.png"/>
        </controls:Panorama.Background>
        ...
        ..
        . // your code
```

To change the Image at code behind use:

```
     private void Panorama_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
     {
         myImg.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Jellyfish.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
     }
```

Its working for me. Hope it helps you too.

Comment: type or namespace "BitmapImage" could not be found! any help? :S

Comment: Got it :) to anyone else just include: using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

Comment: Its not showing the new image :S only removing the old one :S

Comment: Here's my code (the uri is correct): myImg.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("PanoramaBackgroundLloyds.png", UriKind.Relative));

Comment: set PanoramaBackgroundLloyds.png resource type as `content`. And it should be inside the `root folder`.

Comment: Thanks man! Hate to be a pain and keep asking questions, but was just wondering... it goes black between images when sliding... know of a way to remove that? Or set the black to maybe white or a diferent image? Thanks again tho!

Comment: The grid containing the panorama item, apply a background to it. Hope it helps, happy to help :)